# Join Time and Date fields in CartoDB with SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, cartodb

I've imported a dataset into CartoDB. 
The Date field is separated from the Time field, and the latter is in decimal from start of day.

The Date values:

> 2015-10-18T00:00:00Z

The Time values:

> 0.51180555556

The result in the DateTime field should be

> 2015-10-18T12:17:00Z

I want to use CartoDB's own SQL statement to generate that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I could read in [CartoDB's manual](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/sql-api/making-calls/), it is based on PostgreSQL.
In PostgreSQL you have [many options](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html) of converting times and dates.

For instance, in your case, you can use the following conversion and addition of temporal values:

```
SELECT date '2015-10-18T00:00:00Z' + 0.51180555556 * interval '1 day';
```

Given that the data is already stored in a table `T(d date,n foat)` you may use the following query to extract the data:

```
SELECT d + n * interval '1 day' FROM T
```